# How to recreate database in SQLAlchemy from Flask?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy ORM framework from a Flask project. I wanted to add another column to one of my models. After I did, I used `db.session.drop_all()` to drop all current entries in the database, and then I tried recreating a new instance with the new field.

Whenever I tried I get this error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no 
such table: user
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.username AS user_username, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.image_file AS user_image_file 
FROM user]
```

I think I might need to reconstruct the database in some way, but I'm not sure how. I looked into the documentation, but could not find anything useful.

**__init__.py**

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False) #newly added field
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    messages = db.relationship('Message', backref='user', lazy=True)
```

Comment: have you tried to delete file `site.db`?

Comment: `db.drop_all()` drops all the tables, not entries in the tables. You need to run `db.create_all()` to recreate the schema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you used [`db.drop_all()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.drop_all) you dropped all tables so now you can't insert data because there is no table. You need create the table again with [`db.create_all()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) as @SuperShoot mentioned.

You should use something for migrations like `alembic` or [`flask-sqlalchemy`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/).
This way you could add new column to your `ORM`. Run `flask db migrate -m 'new column'`, this will detect changes. Then run `flask db upgrade head` to apply those changes to your database.

Comment: Identity of the tables wont change. Is there a way to reset the ID identity of all tables dynamically?